# Camera capture is too slow

Tags: camera, angstrom

I had being conducting some experimentation with my Beagleboard and camera. The camera was working perfectly well initially. Later I extended my experiments by disabling the 'auto-exposure' and manually setting the value myself. But doing this alone made the camera function to be so slow by about 15x times the previous performance.

What can be the reason?

Comment: Does re-enabling auto-exposure restore the speed? Also, which webcam?

Comment: i am using Logitech-C110.
Yes re-enabling restores the speed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capture speed and exposure time are related -- if you're exposing the CCD for 100 msec per frame, you'll get a maximum of 10 frames per second, whereas exposing the CCD for 1000 msec per frame means you can't get more than 1 frame per second.  Normally you control something like the line exposure time in a CCD, not the frame exposure time, but it's the same idea.

Comment: Were you referring to Frame Transfer CCD? I couldn't fetch much information about line exposure time.

I think this is exactly the reason for slowness.